# Twilio Whatsapp template - add a video

Tags: twilio

I would like to add a video to the Whatsapp template on Twilio (Within the regular process of template submission in Twilio), How should I add the Video to the template?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Templates sent via the Twilio API for WhatsApp do not currently support sending media.